# Visual Studio not showing typescript errors

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am running into s strange problem. I have VS2013 installed with typescript. When I click on save button of a `.ts` file, the ts compiler is invoked, but VS does not show any ts errors. If the compiler fails I just get a message `"Input file contained semantic errors"`.

[image]

Now I don't know where the errors are. Does someone know how to fix this, so I can see the actual errors?

Answer (score 0):

Usually any errors would appear in the "Errors and Warnings" window in Visual Studio.

If you have a case where they aren't appearing, you can try manually running the TypeScript compiler from the command line:

```
tsc yourfile.ts
```

This will output any errors to the command line window.

If you are still stuck, you can supply some code and we can give more specific advice.