# In Visual Studio Professional 2017, where is the typescript compile errors shown?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio Professional 2017, where is the typescript compile errors shown?
I dont see any logs in the OUTPUT window at all, even through I have created a arbitrary sytax error. 
Im using the angular 5 template.

properties set below

[image]

steps to reproduce issue

Using visual studio 2017 professional, create new project using ASP.NET Core Web Application > Angular template ( ASP.NET Core 2.1), manually create syntax error for instance, in app.module.ts, run a build. Notice no output of typescript error is shown in Output window.

Answer (score 0):

Check ts file properties in Solution explorer. If Build action = Content, change it to **`TypeScript`** file

Comment: @sejeetharan, there are way too many ts files to do this on...Which specific TS file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392512/visual-studio-not-showing-typescript-errors

Comment: that link just states that I should run tsc manually for a SINGLE file again, not as helpful. Please provide a direct response , and I can happily upvote if the answer directly solves my issue.